# Hash tables in graph theory

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am reading an article on Hash tables. Here is the text snippet.

> A hash table is useful for any graph theory problem where the nodes
>   have real names instead of numbers. Here, as the input is read,
>   vertices are assigned integers from 1 onwards by order of appearance.
>   Again, the input is likely to have large groups of alphabetized
>   entries. For example, the vertices could be computers. Then if one
>   particular installation  lists its computers as ibm1, ibm2, ibm3, . .
>   . , there could be a dramatic effect on efficiency if a search tree is
>   used.

My quesitons on above text

1. What does author mean "as input is read, verticies are assigned integers from 1 onward" don't we have calculate hash key for input read?
2. What does author mean by "there could be a dramatic effect on efficiency if a search tree is used."?
3. How hash tables are helpful in graph theory problems when compared to search tree?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand that paragraph, but I know why hash tables are useful: with a good hash function they give you roughly O(1) lookup time for exact matches, whereas (balanced) trees give you O(logn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) It's a map not a set, they calculate a hash value of course, but the node is mapped to an integer, and that's the purpose of the map. 

(2) A search tree is O(logn) search, using a map based on search tree will increase time complexity of all ops *O(logn). [for example, BFS will take `O(logV*[V+E))` instead of `O(V+E)`, because of the lookup time.

(3) Hash table is O(1), so time complexity will be better for hash tables, in the average case.

Answer (score 0):

(1) the author could be referencing methods of representing graphs in matrix form, [like this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)

(2) not sure about "search trees", though if you can represent hash tables as a graph, then there are some methods to optimize them, [like this example](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08267.pdf).